# Which GCP service(s) is the best for my use case?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have an image in Artifact Registry that does a unit of work:

- it expects input files inside a certain directory (let's call it main_input)
- runs them, does some sequences of computation, and outputs results into an output folder in Google Storage

The run time of each does not exceed 30 minutes, but I have thousands of such runs to perform.

Inside a single VM, I can create various containers from this image by mounting the main_input directory inside the container to the correct ones on the host, and run.

However, I wonder if Cloud Run is a more scalable solution for this? or shall I look at other services/strategies?

Answer (score 0):

Managing thousands of runs is not an easy task, you can use a scheduler like airflow or argo worfkflows to run the tasks and restart them if needed.

For the containers environment, I propose Kubernetes (GKE) over Cloud Run, for some reason:

- you have more permissions than Cloud Run
- to be agnostic from GCP (your code can work on other platforms like AWS)
- better management for apps configurations and secrets, and supported with all the CI/CD tools
- less expensive: you can create scalable preemptible node pools to reduce the cost and add a lot of resources when needed
- you can use the same cluster to run other applications for your company
- you can use open source tools for log collections, monitoring, HTTP reverse proxy, ...